# Values in second columns of GPValueTable Parameter reset after tool is ran

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox, value-table

I am trying to create a `.pyt` python toolbox tool in ArcGIS pro and the issue I'm running into is that Values in second columns of `GPValueTable` Parameter reset after tool is ran.
The parameter created is simply:

```py
param = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Value Table",
        name="Value_Table",
        datatype="GPValueTable",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
```

So for this specific parameter I have two columns defined in the SAME class like this:

```py
param.columns = [["GPString", "Column"],["GPString", "Matched Column"]]
```

I then allow the user to choose the fields they want in the matched column and the values of that dropdown menu populate in my updateParameters method like this:

```py
def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
        validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
        has been changed."""

        if parameters[1].altered and parameters[0].altered and parameters[2].hasBeenValidated and parameters[3].hasBeenValidated:             

            layer_0 = parameters[1].value
            fields_list = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(layer_0)]
            fields_list.insert(0, "Empty")
            parameters[2].filters[1].list = fields_list
            
            row_type = parameters[0].value
            if row_type == "CATV/Phone":
                parameters[2].values = [["Owner Name",fields_list[0]]]
            if row_type == "Gas":
                parameters[2].values =[["Owner Name",fields_list[0]],["Pipeline Name",fields_list[0]]]
            if row_type == "Irrigation":
                parameters[2].values = [["Owner Name",fields_list[0]]]
            if row_type == "Power":
                parameters[2].values = [["Owner Name",fields_list[0]]]
            if row_type == "Sewer":
                parameters[2].values = [["Owner Name",fields_list[0]]]
            if row_type == "Water":
                parameters[2].values = [["Owner Name",fields_list[0]]]
            if row_type == "Road Centerline":                    
                parameters[2].values = [["Owner Name",fields_list[0]],["Street Name",fields_list[0]],["Confirmed ROW", fields_list[0]]]
```

The first value I assigned to be "empty" just in case the user doesn't find a matching column. I need these matching columns to retain their values when my execute method is run: My execute method is simple:

```py
def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        value_table = parameters[2].value
        value_dict = {}
        for value in value_table:
            value_dict[value[0]] = value[1]
        arcpy.AddMessage(value_dict)
        
        value_list = list(value_dict.values())
        key_list = list(value_dict.keys())
        
        arcpy.AddMessage(value_dict.values())
        arcpy.AddMessage(value_dict.keys())
```

Every time I print the values, the keys are just "empty". meaning that the values that I chose from the drop down menu for the second column "matched column" in the `GPValueTable` Parameter are somehow already reset by the time the reach the execute method. I need these values to be retained but I'm not sure why they aren't being retained.

Comment: So are you saying the interface behaves as expected, fields are in dropdowns you can complete your value table but when you come to click on run it appears to have forgotten everything?